# Registering the generic typed declarations in Angular Module

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following typescript service code that I wish to expose via a new Angular module.

**Generic Service**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { AuthHeaders } from "./auth.headers";

export abstract class BaseHttpService<T> {
  baseAPIUrl: string;
  serviceAPISegment: string;
  private requestOptions = {
    headers: this.authHeaders.getHeaders()
  };

  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private authHeaders: AuthHeaders
  ) {}

  get<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T[]>(
      `${this.baseAPIUrl}\\${this.serviceAPISegment}`,
      this.requestOptions
    );
  }
}
```

**Module Declaration**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BaseHttpService } from "./asyncServices/http/base.http.service";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BaseHttpService
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {}
```

I get error in the BaseHttpService which is given below

> ERROR in src/app/shared/shared.module.ts(11,5): error TS2322: Type
>   'typeof BaseHttpService' is not assignable to type 'any[] |
>   Type'.   Type 'typeof BaseHttpService' is not assignable to type
>   'Type'.
>       Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

I have tried the following 
BaseHttpService
BaseHttpService<>

which all are not working. Please suggest the suitable way to register the service in this module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which module you want to use it, you have to use a `{ provide ..., useClass ...}` construct inside of the module you import the `SharedModule`. So if you want to use it in some kind of module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {  provide: BaseHttpService<any>, useClass: SomeKindHttpService<any> }
  ]
})
export class SomeKindModule {}
```

and have your service extend the BaseHttpService

```
export class SomeKindHttpService<T> extends BaseHttpService<T> {
  constructor(
    httpClient: HttpClient,
    authHeaders: AuthHeaders
   ) {
     super(httpClient, authHeaders);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. A service is not a declaration, but provided. It should be in the "provided" property of the module instantiation. Also, how would you expect the Angular DI system to figure out how to provide an abstract class? It would need to know what `T` is, and it has no way to figure that one out.

Answer (score 1):

The service is abstract and so it cannot be instantiated. You should make it non abstract or let another service extend it.

Also the service should ne be added to the declaration property of the modue, but to the property "providers".